# No Configuration Found for Key while reading Config File In spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi I'm trying to read configuration from my configuration file in `spark/scala`.

I've wriiten below code.

```scala
val conf = com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.load(args(0))
var url=conf.getString("parameters.spark-hive.url")
var db=conf.getString("parameters.spark-hive.dbname")
val sparksession = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("myapp")
  .config("spark.sql.hive.hiveserver2.jdbc.url",url)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```

Below is my `application.conf` file(`src/main/resources/application.conf`)

```
parameters {
  spark-hive {
  url = """jdbc://xxxxxxxxxxxx""",
  dbname =   """bdname"""
  }
}
```

and using below `Spark-submit` command:

```sh
spark-submit \
> --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=-Dconfig.file=application.conf"\
> --verbose \
> --class classjarname \
> project_jar
> /path/config-1.2.0.jar \
> /path/application.conf
```

but getting below  error.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'parameters' Note:-I'm genetarting Jar using Maven and using HDP 3.X
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'parameters specifies that it is not able to load the key parameters. This is the entry of your conf file which is pointing to your config file not properly loaded or not getting parsed properly. So I would suggest reading the file and then try with the next step i.e using these parameters to create the Sparksession.

Answer (score 1):

You could print out the actual value of `args(0)` to see where the (full) path refers to. This worked for me:

```scala
com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.parseFile(new java.io.File(args(0)))
```

Additional remark:

- not sure what `project_jar` means in your submit command
- there seems to be a typo with `hive-url` as the code when building the SparkSession does not match your configuration.

Comment: project_jar-->Jar File ( code  Jar (generated  from  maven Eclipse).                                     hive-url:-Yes It was typo I've Updated this

Comment: what is then the `/path/config-1.2.0.jar` ?

Comment: I've added this jar using pom.xml in eclipse but still it was giving error so I placed this somewhere 'MyHDFS' location and giving that path.I have my all the jar and application.conf file in the same folder at HDFS

Comment: '/path/config-1.2.0.jar' this Jar is for  "com.typesafe.config".

Answer (score 0):

Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'parameters specifies that it is not able to load the key parameters. This is the entry of your conf file which is pointing to your config file not properly loaded or not getting parsed properly. So I would suggest reading the file and then try with the next step i.e using these parameters to create the Sparksession. Try below to read the file contents if loaded properly

```
import scala.io.Source
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

val filename = ConfigFactory.load(args(0))
for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines) {
println(line)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to show you an easy example of how to use `com.typesafe.config` library.

This is my `application.properties` under the resources directory.

```
## Structured Streaming device
device.zookeeper = quickstart.cloudera:2181
device.bootstrap.server = quickstart.cloudera:9092
device.topic = device



device.execution.mode = local

device.data.host = quickstart.cloudera

device.data.port = 44444

## HBase

device.zookeeper.quorum = quickstart.cloudera
device.zookeeper.port = 2181
device.window = 1
```

[image: folder structure directory]

and this is the code to get the properties, `args(0) == device`

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = ConfigFactory.load // get Confs
    val envProps: Config = conf.getConfig(args(0)) // args(0) == device
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster(envProps.getString("execution.mode")).setAppName("Device Signal") // get execution.mode conf
    val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(envProps.getInt("window"))) // get window conf
    streamingContext.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    val broadcastConfig = streamingContext.sparkContext.broadcast(envProps)
    val topicsSet = Set(envProps.getString("topic")) // get topic conf
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> envProps.getString("bootstrap.server"), // get bootstrap.server conf
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> "1",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
    )
    val logData: DStream[String] = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      streamingContext,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](topicsSet, kafkaParams)
    ).map(record =>{
      record.value
    })
```